# Change font size in figure environment

Tags: floats, fontsize

I'm writing a thesis-like document and I have sketches/figures made in TikZ and plots/graph made in gnuplot with the epslatex terminal. In the gnuplot manual it says if the font is not specified it will inherit the font and size from the context in the document. I'm not sure how TikZ does it.

I would like to reduce the font size of the text in the figures. How do I do that? In case it matters, I'm using the KOMA `scrreprt` class. I would very much like a way to do it so I don't have to modify the TikZ code or the tex-file produced by gnuplot. This question is *not* about the figure captions but the text in the figures themselves, although I will change the caption font size as well, obviously :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

```
\begin{figure}
  \small % or any other font-changing command
  % code for including the picture
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I assume gnuplot places the text on the plot assuming it will be shown in normal size. So I guess that may lead to some problems, but I haven't encountered any. Such problems would probably only appear if I made the text larger, anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package to change the fontsize for all figures (while at the same time keeping the font size of tables or other floats unchanged):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
(Text inside a figure)
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
(Text inside a table)
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]